# SliverPesistentHeader and lazy loading

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm using a `CustomScrollView` with a `SliverList+SliverChildBuilderDelegate` to lazy load a list while scrolling.
I want some of my list items to behave like a `SliverPersistentHeader` - but obviously I cannot return a Sliver from my `SliverChildBuilderDelegate`.

Essentially, what I would like to know, is - can I use a builder to generate my list of slivers such that I don't need to know ahead of time, what kind of sliver each item will be?

Thanks

Comment: what is the difference between using [sticky_headers](https://pub.dev/packages/sticky_headers) and your case?

Comment: The problem with that is it doesn't meet my criteria. sticky_headers is a list of groups, not a list of items - hence I must know how many items in the group, when the group is built. Not lazy-load friendly.